# mysql select inside limit

Tags: mysql, select, limit

```
select
  id
from
  tableABC
limit (select count(id) from tableCBA), 1
```

If I need select in limit as I have shown here in sample code, how can I do this in mySql? This is only simplified code for purpose of this forum, otherwise this is a part of sophisticated case when else select.

Comment: Are you trying to select the last row of the table? Show your schema.

Comment: I don't you can do this in MySQL. You can use sub-selects but **not** on the LIMIT.  I would suggest to either code this into the client (maybe php?). Otherwise create Stored Procedure. The later shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly have a dynamic value for limit, but your query can be re-written *without* the limit, as follows:

```
set i := (select count(*) from tableCBA);
select id
from tableABC
where (i := i-1) = 0;
```

This will return the nth row, where n is the number of rows in tableCBA;

Comment: not sure if this is performance wise such a great idea? Do like the creativity.

Answer (score 0):

```
select @LimitRowsCount1=count(id) from tableCBA;

PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT id from tableABC LIMIT ?";

EXECUTE STMT USING @LimitRowsCount1;
```