# how can i use number of rows in a table as limit value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying get the latest 10 rows and delete remaining rows of a particular id with one query.

Here is my query:

```
DELETE 
FROM `courses` 
WHERE customer_id = 11 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `courses` WHERE customer_id = 11);
```

Please anyone help me to recognize the error in this query.

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you  getting or what behaviour are you getting?

Comment: i tested above query in mysql and i got this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `courses` WHERE customer_id = 11)' at line 1

Comment: @pooja  what error?

Comment: You could try `LIMIT` combined with a reverse ordering (DESC), see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: possible duplicates of:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567214/mysql-select-inside-limit

Comment: @AlivetoDie here is error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `courses` WHERE customer_id = 11)' at line 1

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i tried

Comment: @AlivetoDie  i got solution please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution, here is the query :

```
$sql1="DELETE FROM `courses` WHERE customer_id =11 AND id NOT IN (SELECT id
  FROM (SELECT id FROM `courses` WHERE customer_id =11 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) AS foo)";
$conn->query($sql1);
```

By above query, we get the latest 10 rows and delete the remaining rows of a particular id.